# Mongoose no guarda arrays

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy intentando guardar los datos en mongoDb con nodejs. Para ello utilizo un schema llamado Champion que inicializo en el controlador, cuando guardo se queda todo bien menos stats y points, que queda una array en blanco. Como puedo solucionar?

Schema de champion:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const ChampionSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    faction: {type: String},
    type: {type: String}, // 0 hp, 1 apoyo, 2 ataque, 3 defensa 
    image: {type: String},
    rarity: {type: Number}, //0 comun, 1 poco frecuente, 2 raro, 3 epico, 4 legendario
    affinity: {type: Number}, //0 Azul, 1 Rojo, 2 Verde, 3 Vacio
    stats: [{
        hp: {type:String, default: '0'},
        atk: {type:String, default: '0'},
        def: {type:String, default: '0'},
        vel: {type:String, default: '0'},
        pcrit: {type:String, default: '0'},
        dcrit: {type:String, default: '0'},
        resist: {type:String, default: '0'},
        punt: {type:String, default: '0'}
    }], 
    points: [[{
        campaign: {type:String, default: '0'},
        defarena: {type:String, default: '0'},
        atkarena: {type:String, default: '0'},
        minotaurus: {type:String, default: '0'},
        clan: {type:String, default: '0'},
        hidra: {type:String, default: '0'},
        golem: {type:String, default: '0'},
        spider: {type:String, default: '0'},
        drake: {type:String, default: '0'},
        fire: {type:String, default: '0'},
        force: {type:String, default: '0'},
        magic: {type:String, default: '0'},
        spirit: {type:String, default: '0'},
        void: {type:String, default: '0'},
        factions: {type:String, default: '0'}
    }]],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Champion',ChampionSchema);
```

Creamos un nuevo campeon con newChampion = new Champion(bodyChamp). El bodyChamp es generado por una función que nos devuelve el objeto con la siguiente estructura:

```
  name: 'prova',
  type: '0',
  faction: 'hidalgos',
  rarity: '3',
  affinity: '1',
  stats: [
    hp: '50',   atk: '50',
    def: '50',  vel: '123',
    pcrit: '',  dcrit: '',
    resist: '', punt: ''
  ],
  points: [
    campaign: '', defarena: '1',
    atkarena: '', minotaurus: '3',
    clan: '',     hidra: '4',
    golem: '',    spider: '2',
    drake: '',    fire: '',
    force: '',    magic: '',
    spirit: '',   void: '',
    factions: ''
  ]
]
```

Muchas gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Y como estás guardando la data en la colección?, porque a los datos de stats y points deberías hacerles un push, y stats en el schema tiene una lista de objetos en un array que está dentro de otro array, esto es así a propósito?

Comment: Los valores de `stats` y `points` que muestras en el objeto `bodyChamp` no son correctos, tienes allí un problema de sintaxis. Un tipo Array no puede tener la estructura que muestras en tu código para esos campos. Por favor, copia y pega exactamente lo que se genera en `bodyChamp`. Por otro lado, en tu esquema, el campo `points` no parece una estructura correcta, a menos que tengas razones específicas para crear un Array de Array's y que el contenido de cada Array anidado sea un objeto. Saludos